# Equal button of the Calculator project is not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, mouseevent, calculator

I belive my issue is with the operate function. When i click the '=' button, it does not change the result on the displayer. The displayer value keeps being the contents clicked and does not proceed with the calculation.

```js
const displayer = document.querySelector("#inputBox");
const btn = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
const btnOp = document.querySelectorAll("button.operator");
const btnEqual = document.querySelector("button.equal");
const btnDeleter = document.querySelector("button.delete");
let string = "";

const clearContent = () => {
  string = "";
  return (displayer.value = string);
};

Array.from(btn).forEach((number) => {
  number.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // check if the event works correctly on the target
    console.log(e.target);
    string += e.target.textContent;
    displayer.value = string;

    if (number === btnDeleter) {
      clearContent();
    }

    if (number === btnEqual) {
      operate();
      string = displayer.value;
    }
  });
});

const operate = (num1, num2, op) => {
  if (op === "-") {
    return (displayer.value = num1 - num2);
  }

  if (op === "+") {
    return (displayer.value = num1 + num2);
  }

  if (op === "/") {
    return (displayer.value = num1 / num2);
  }

  if (op === "*") {
    return (displayer.value = num1 * num2);
  }
};
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="calculator">
      <input type="text" id="inputBox" placeholder="0" />
      <div>
        <button class="button operator">AC</button>
        <button class="button delete">DEL</button>
        <button class="button operator">%</button>
        <button class="button operator">/</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="button">7</button>
        <button class="button">8</button>
        <button class="button">9</button>
        <button class="button operator">*</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="button">4</button>
        <button class="button">5</button>
        <button class="button">6</button>
        <button class="button operator">-</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="button">1</button>
        <button class="button">2</button>
        <button class="button">3</button>
        <button class="button operator">+</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button class="button">00</button>
        <button class="button">0</button>
        <button class="button">.</button>
        <button class="button equal">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried an event listener for the equal but it did not work either. i tried setting my variable     `string` to `""` inside the `operate` function but to no avail. If i use the `operate` function inside devtools it works correctly and even changes the value on the displayer but the event listener is not functioning.

Comment: Your `operate` function takes 3 arguments, but you provide none when you call it. Also you don't need those returns.